# How to fix the "whatsapp://" protocol click in iOS Homescreen Chrome Shortcut broken after latest iOS update to 12.2?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, web-applications

**Previous / Working State:**

Javascript was fetching some simple date/time values from HTML form & was setting string `"whatsapp://send?text="+encodeURIComponet(str)` as href of an `a` element.

On iOS, I opened the link on Safari, selected Bookmarks -> Add to Home Screen. All was working i.e. on pressing "Go", javascript ran, fetched values, generated string, & then Safari Autoredirected to Whatsapp App with a list of contacts to choose for message, as well as Share link worked if clicked manually.

href.value = `whatsapp://send?text=Apr-21%3A%20Dav%20OUT%20at%2007%3A19pm`

**After I updated the iPhone 8 to latest iOS 12.2 three days ago:**

Same setup, but now after clicking button "Go", Safari shows the following URL in address/status bar & a white page showing

```
Safari cannot open the page because it
cannot redirect to locations starting
with "whatsapp:"
```

Manual click & element.click() both gives above error. Same everyhting in iOS Chrome or iOS Safari browser are working as intented, but gives error only when used from Add to Homescreen App.

**My Code**

HTML

```html
<form>
<label for="date">Date</label><input id="date" name="date" type="date" required>
<label for="what">In/Out</label>
<select id="what" name="what" required>
  <option value="tIn">IN</option>
  <option value="tOut">OUT</option>
</select>
<label for="when">Time</label>
<input id="when" name="when" type="time" step=60 required><!-- step=60 will show only HH:MM -->
<input type="submit" onClick="process()" value="Go">
<a id="share">Share</a>
```

JS

```js
function process(){
  var date = document.getElementById("date").value;
  var what = document.getElementById("what").value;
  var when = document.getElementById("when").value;
  var waStr = waFormat(date,what,when);

  var share = document.getElementById("share");
  share.href = "whatsapp://send?text=" + encodeURIComponent(waStr);
  share.click();
}

//return string for whatsapp link
function waFormat(waDate,waWhat,waWhen){
  var sp = " ";
  waDate = waDate.split("-");
  var mon = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
  waDate = mon[(waDate[1]-1)] + "-" + waDate[2]; 
  waWhat = (waWhat == "tIn") ? "IN" : "OUT";
  waWhen = waWhen.split(":");
  var apm = "am";
  if(waWhen[0]>12){
    waWhen[0] = waWhen[0]-12;
    apm = "pm";
  }
  waWhen = ("0" + waWhen[0]).slice(-2) + ":" + waWhen[1] + apm;
  return waDate + ": "+ waWhat + sp + "at" + sp + waWhen;
}
```

I switched between encode()/encodeURI()/encodeURIComponent, but no avail.

Please help. Where could be the problem for that whatsapp:// not working in HomeScreen Safari App? I could use https://wa.me link but would also like to find if whatsapp:// has stopped working?

It works when same page is opened from Safari/Any, does NOT work when opened from HomeScreen App in iOS

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem with URI's starting with webcal://

Answer (score 5):

I've ran into this problem too. For my it worked to move away from the url scheme `whatsapp://` and use the following guide https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/26000030/.

> To create your own link with a pre-filled message that will automatically appear in the text field of a chat, use `https://wa.me/whatsappphonenumber/?text=urlencodedtext` where `whatsappphonenumber` is a full phone number in international format and `URL-encodedtext` is the URL-encoded pre-filled message.
>
> Example: `https://wa.me/15551234567?text=I'm%20interested%20in%20your%20car%20for%20sale`
>
> To create a link with just a pre-filled message, use `https://wa.me/?text=urlencodedtext`
>
> Example: `https://wa.me/?text=I'm%20inquiring%20about%20the%20apartment%20listing`
>
> After clicking on the link, you will be shown a list of contacts you can send your message to.